# Problem integrating Adsense with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

(Cross-posted to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/problem-integrating-adsen-with-google-analytics))

I've [posted it once](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=1cb907196596459c&hl=en) to the adsense ad forum, but as usual Google does not respond to help requests, and I got no real answers.

I am having issues integrating my Adsense and Analytics accounts on my website - http://draw3cards.com. The accounts seem integrated from Adsense (I get a working "go to analytics" link), but all the analytics are flatlined - they show zero revenues although they are non-zero.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I strongly recommend asking over at the [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site, they're probably better informed to assist.

Comment: And it's called AdSense :)

Comment: @Farseeker: why? This seems like a webmaster question to me.

Comment: @Farseeker - it's definitely off topic for web apps.

Comment: @Kino - I never said the question should be closed here, but the people at WebApps are probably just as knowledgable. If the question was off-topic I would have closed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you selected your domain as the Primary domain? If you have multiple sites you will need to select a primary domain, then put a small bit of code on each of the other sites.

To set the primary domain and get the required code, from Analytics home click the "Edit AdSense linking settings" link at the top of the page. First tick the sites you want to link. On the next step you can choose your primary domain, then get the code for the others.

Comment: Alright, I updated the primary domain, it really wasn't the one that I had. I will see if this works.

Comment: Wonderful, it works!

Answer (score 2):

> I've posted it once to the adsense ad
>   forum, but as usual Google does not
>   respond to help requests, and I got no
>   real answers.

Google are pathetic at interacting with human beings. If anything brings that company down, I suspect it will be that.

> I am having issues integrating my
>   Adsense and Analytics accounts. The
>   accounts seem integrated from Adsense
>   (I get a working "go to analytics"
>   link), but all the analytics are
>   flatlined - they show zero revenues
>   although they are non-zero.

The first thing to check is that the ID at the top of your page is the right one. You should have a bit of text which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-ABCDEFGH-J";
</script>
```

where `ABCDEFGH-J` is the number that Google gave you. You can check it's the right one using the "Analytics Settings" page of Google Analytics. If this number is wrong then the integration will not work correctly. Then at the bottom of the page there should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-ABCDEFGH-J");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

Comment: The text 'window.google_analytics_uacct' doesn't appear on my page. I added the address of my website to the question.