# Analytics not showing Adsense data

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem integrating Adsense with Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/problem-integrating-adsense-with-google-analytics)

I already posted on the analytics help forum but nobody replied, so I thought I would ask here.

Basically, I have an Adsense account that and use it to show adds on 2 websites, and an Analytics account for these two websites.

Now I linked the account ages ago (when I only had one website in the analytics account), but now that I have added the second website no data shows for it. For the first website, I get the data normally, for the second website, I get the weird error saying I need to connect to my Adsense account first.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting the accounts? Perhaps your old account uses a different email address.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Turns out I needed to add another piece of code for non-primary profiles in my analytics account. It works now.

Comment: Could you provide that as an answer rather than a comment so it can help others out in the future?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles the answer is here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/problem-integrating-adsense-with-google-analytics