# How do I break the infinite loop that results when I try and link my Google AdSense and Google Analytics accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

It seems that it is currently impossible to link a Google Analytics and AdSense accounts. I this true? I am definitely an administrator in both accounts (both use the same Google login too)

1. From the homepage on my Adsense account I click on the link that says: "Integrate with Google Analytics" 
   [image]

2)...and then on the "Go to Analytics" links,

[image]

3) I receive a message on my Adsense page

[image]

4) ...and I get taken to the home page of my analytics account in a separate window

[image]

5)...from where I navigate to the Admin | Data Sources | Adsense page:

[image]

6) I click on the Link Accounts link and I end up exactly where I started and when I go to Account Settings page in Adsense, I get this:

[image]

**I seem never able to actually link the two accounts. What on earth am I doing wrong?**

PS A similar question has been logged [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/problem-integrating-adsense-with-google-analytics),  but I think it is very old and the answers are very out of date.

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like other people were having the same problem](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/V7VVTLBst8s/84RJtjTMZZcJ) User ColeDes posted this solution:

1. Ok, go to the Analytics Home page where it says "My Dashboard"
2. Go to the top right hand corner and click "Admin" on the orange bar next to "Help"
3. Click on the last option which says "Remarketing Lists"
4. Click on "link your Adwords account" yes click for Adsense too.
5. Under "Data Sources" there should be 2 tabs "Adwords" and "Adsense", click Adsense and link your account.

It sounds like some people are still having problems and it may be a bug on Google's end.