# Adsense alternative for a "Sex Education" website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I am creating a nice and niche "Sex Education" website. No porn, nothing offensive and no scams. I would love to place Google Adsense but they do not allow ads on adult sites.

I would like to know what advertising and link-exchange like should I place on my site. My sole objective is to cover the server costs and salary of one or two persons.

*(In this way, it is different from [Best alternative to Adsense for a small website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/best-alternative-to-adsense-for-a-small-website)).*

Comment: What kind of traffic are you expecting? If it's highly targeted traffic, affiliate marketing would probably be better. Lots of eyeballs, but not very targeted and you will be better off with CPM.

Answer (score 7):

Sexual education isn't necessarily adult content. Here in the U.S. sex ed. is taught to students in elementary school (around 4th grade, I think). So just because you use words describing genitalia or sex doesn't mean it's adult content. There are healthcare sites with sex education content that have been approved for Adsense. I'd just contact Adsense and ask them for specific guidelines for your type of site.

Comment: You'd be surprised of the strange things that can set off Google's alarms. I wrote a piece once on Beaches in France and within the article, I mentioned that a particular beach was a nude beach and I could not, for the life of me, get an ad to show.