# Does it make sense to implement own ad system on a website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, user-friendly

I've done research on viability of AdSense to put on our website and found that this is probably a bad approach for the following reasons:

1. The ads are quite often not relevant at all for users
2. You can't make enough money even if you are huge(see answer for [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/621/adsense-is-it-worth-setting-up) for example)
3. People are annoyed by this

So I had the following idea in mind - instead of putting AdSense or some other ad tools maybe it makes sense to implement custom ad tool? I'll explain:
The site I am working on is focused on quite niche field, i.e. all users are interested in quite narrow services and products. It might be good to make direct contracts with companies to advertise their products, meaning for each ad we show on a website we talked directly with the company, discussing the ad campaign, making it more personal endeavor. I see some benefits of this like:

1. We can show ads that we are sure will be of value for users
2. We can prevent adBlock from blocking it
3. Since we control everything we can make it as user friendly as possible
4. Probably will be more profitable

Are there some disadvantages here? Do I miss something? On the first glance this seems more reasonable, at least for niche website, but to be honest I don't see it implemented very often(or I at least not aware of it when I look at ads). Or maybe there are some legal issues?

The only disadvantages I see for now are getting initial companies interested and extra development time.

Edit:
To avoid opinion-based answers I am asking if there are companies that use this approach and shared some data. I couldn't google well since this is not popular method I suppose.

Comment: Sorry but this question is very subjective and will attract opinionated answers, as there is no right or wrong to what you are asking, only ideas and extended discussion. You may be able to edit your question and make it less discussion based.

Comment: @SimonHayter, I understand, but people may know cases of such system that were implemented and have statistics reports, so maybe somebody have not opinion but statistics.

Comment: There will be no solid statistics in your case, since there is just far to many variables. Conversion of adverts varies from page to page, from niche to niche, you simply won't find an answer to your question, only opinions. You may be able to edit the question but I doubt whatever you try will still make it opinionated based. You might save some time asking in our chat channel, since it looks like your be better of with a discussion with other webmasters.

Comment: @SimonHayter, OK, I'll try to research more and come back if I will be able to make more specific question. For now feel free to delete this one if you think so.

Comment: Use Google DFP - it allows the best of both worlds. If you can't get any adverts, it shows AdSense but if you managed to secure adverts from a partner, DFP will show these instead. Advantages will be the usual "not reinventing the wheel"

Comment: Completely wrong. Adsense are the most accurate ad platform in the history of mankind that's why Google gathers so much information about everyone; in order to show relevant ads per user.